# cordova-plugin-media doesn't trigger mediaStatus callback on Android

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm using the plugin `cordova-plugin-media` to read audio files on my ionic project.

Here some code :

```
var onMediaLoad = function() {};
var onMediaError = function() {};
var onMediaStatus = function(mediaStatus) {
  console.log(mediaStatus);
};

var media = new Media(scope.composantParams['src'],
                       onMediaLoad,
                       onMediaError,
                       onMediaStatus);
media.play();
```

The mediaStatus function callback is never triggered even if the media is playing.
But on iOS, it's working fine.

The plugin version is `2.1.0`

Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

I just needed to update the plugin to the version 2.2.0 that fix callback issues.